# How to re-rank documents based on their attributes rather than just their field relevance?

Tags: apache, search, solr, ranking

I'm trying to use Solr to re-rank document results based relevance to the user searching. For example, if I search `joann*`this could return documents where the `Name` field is anything from joanna to joanne. What I'm trying to do is to return documents that match on certain attributes that I have as well-- this could be something like us both having the field `Location = "NYC"`.

So my question is two fold- is there a way to grab and handle a users information when they are making a query and also is there a way to re-rank based on these additional field values? Would this look more like writing some code or just an expanded query?

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me like you are talking about functionality that [Query Reranking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Re-Ranking) exactly provides. Did you check that out?

Comment: Yeah, I realized how to go about it just now. However, I'm still confused about the difference between weighting between qf and bf. Couldnt I have something like qf = `name^5.1 login^1.5` and then bq = `name(tim*)^4 location = NY`? I know qf is also used to actually filter out results, but otherwise aren't these about the same?

Comment: you are asking about edismax specific things. qf is to set what fields to query on (with what weight), bf it to add boost functions (not simple fields) to additionally influence the score.